# Node JS connection establishment between two server

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-request

In my sample project, I have used Google recaptcha. I need to verify captcha response at back end (Node JS). In NodeJS, I have used request module to connect with google server. But, I got some error like following

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.217.166.100:443
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
```

**Node JS**

```
  formData = {
  secret: 'xxxxxx',
  response: 'yyyyyy'
  }

  request.post({
    url: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
    form: formData
  },
  function (err, httpResponse, body) {
     if (err) throw err;
     if (body) {
       res.send(body);
     }
  });
```

When I am trying to set proxy to this above NodeJS code like following...

```
 formData = {
    secret: 'xxxxxx',
    response: 'yyyyyy'
 }

 request.post({
     url: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
     form: formData,
     proxy: '172.217.166.100' /// Google server IP
 },
 function (err, httpResponse, body) {
   if (err) throw err;
   if (body) {
    res.send(body);
   }
 });
```

I got these errors....

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\Desktop\project\Backend\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've specified something like,

```
proxy: '172.217.166.100' /// Google server IP
```

which is wrong, as you can't determine the IP address of google since it is dynamic and often changes it.

You can obtain a latest proxy IP from the below link,

https://code.google.com/archive/p/recaptcha/wikis/FirewallsAndRecaptcha.wiki

The latest available IP's are,

> ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.249.80.0/20
>   ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:66.102.0.0/20
>   ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:207.126.144.0/20
>   ip4:173.194.0.0/16

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Muthukumar Can you please check my updated reply stated above?

Comment: I have checked your updated reply.....My problem is in NodeJS, not in google server ip address.....Google captcha response verification is working fine in POSTMAN....If I try to verify over NodeJS, I got these error